# IE 11 considers pseudo content as part of element content

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-11, pseudo-element

I have run into a problem for which I don't have a solid solution, other than to create a workaround by using `data`-attributes. However, I find the behaviour I'm encountering very strange and wonder if there's a better way around it.

Consider the following piece of code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="test">This is a test!</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#test:after
{
    content: "...This shouldn't be part of text()!";
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("click", "#test", function () {
        alert($(this).text());
    });
});
```

The problem I'm dealing with is that IE 11 seems to take the content in the `:after` pseudo-selector as part of the content in the div. Meaning that when clicked on the div, IE 11 will display an alert saying:

`This is a test!...This shouldn't be part of the text()!`

However, I expected an alert saying:

`This is a test!`

Both Firefox and Chrome are displaying the latter alert. I would like to know if it's possible to make IE also display the latter alert without making use of extra `data-`-attributes or the likes.

Here's a **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ZiNNED/5zvbchey/)** for this example.

Comment: It works perfect in IE9 & IE10!

Comment: Internet Explorer 11 at moment it's full of this kind of bugs.
Just force it to start in compatible mode

Comment: Works for me: IE 11.0.9600

Comment: @strah Really?? I tested my fiddle in IE 11.0.9600.16384 and it's not working...

Comment: @dippas That's at least good to know :) Now for IE 11... Which does seem to work for strah strangely enough...

Comment: @ZiNNED Mine is IE 11.0.9600.17207

Comment: @ZiNNED http://i.imgur.com/g9p9yR8.png

Comment: @strah Looks like a(nother) bug in IE 11 which fortunately seems to be crushed in a minor update then. Thanks for "solving" this! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Mr. E's answer, I thought of a possible solution. I could take the content by taking the `html()` and then rewrap this inside a dummy `div`, from which I take the `text()` again. It seems like a whole bunch of stuff to do for something so simple, but it works.

**HTML**

```
<div id="test"><span>This is a test!</span></div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("click", "#test", function () {
        var html = $(this).html();
        var text = $("<div />").html(html).text();
        alert(text);
    });
});
```

See this updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ZiNNED/5zvbchey/4/)**.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing .text() to .html() like: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/5zvbchey/1/). It works fine on IE 11.0.9600.17351 (With your version and with this version)

code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("click", "#test", function () {
        alert($(this).html());
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but that's not gonna work for me. If for example the text is wrapped in a `span` element, these tags will also show, which I don't want. However, your solution has provided me with an alternative solution, so I thank you for that. :)